# numpy summation of elementwise product along specific direction

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I have two different dimension numpy array, lets say A and B, defined as follows

```
A = np.random.rand(3,3,10)
B = np.random.rand(3,3)
```

I'm trying to calculate the sum of elementwise product between A and B along the third dimension of A.

```
ans = []
for i in range(10):
    ans.append(np.sum(B*A[:,:,i]))
```

Is there any better way to do this?  cause I feel its slow when data gets larger.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try [broadcasting](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.broadcast.html) the missing dimension:

```
(A * B[...,None]).sum(axis=(0,1))
```